# How can I print out an aligned text as output in C?

Tags: c

I want to print output like this

[image: a]

How can I make changes to the code so that I can print exactly like shown in the picture?

Here is my code:

```
void readToArr (int ar[MAX][ROW]) { // Function header
    int i, j;
// Reading from text file
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        for (j=0; j< ROW; j++)
            fscanf(myFile, "%d", &ar[i][j]);

// Display (print) output to screen / console
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j< ROW; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", ar[i][j]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 in `%10d` ought to be sufficient as a field width specifier for your `printf` call

Comment: And use `putc('\n')` after each row.

Comment: It is kind of arbitrary until you try to display it, but the second dimension in a 2D array is generally referred to as the "column" but you have `j` representing a row.  Was that your intent?  Because unless you include cursor location control, you will necessarily have the row iteration as the outer loop.  Needs clearer specification in any event.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate the output you get (no need for input, just use hardcoded inits) and show the output you get and describe the problem you see. Doing that might even help you to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Globals are invariably bad and there is little to justify making `myFile` global here.  Pass it in as a `FILE*` argument to the function, or pass the file name and open/close it in the function.  How does this code behave if the file does not have the hard coded number of rows/columns that the code requires?  Badly is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to specify the field width in the format specifier and output a new-line for each row:

```
        for (j=0; j< ROW; j++)
        {
            printf("%10d ", ar[i][j]);
        } 

        // New row
        printf( "\n" ) ;
```

You'll need a field width of 10 for 32-bit `int`, or 20 for 64-bit unless your application guarantees some other range limit.  The space after the format specifier guarantees at least a space between two maximum length integers.